# painting from an external method

Tags: java, applet, java-2d

In my applet I have a method `paint` that paints on screen.

```
public void init() {
  addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
                    storeCoordinates(evt,Graphics g); // results in error
                }
    });
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
      // do something
}

public void storeCoordinates(MouseEvent evt , Graphics g) {
      // from this method i want to modify the scene painted by paint
}
```

Now in another method I want to modify **a bit of** a scene that was painted by the `paint` method. How can I do this ? Like I want to draw blue lines using `g.drawLine(.,.,.,.)` from another method.

The above snippet generates an error saying `) expected` `; expected` , `cannot find symbol variable Graphics` when i call the function from `mouseMoved`

Comment: my question are you painting Graphics2D to the Applet or JApplet

Comment: @ mKorbel to the JApplet

Comment: Hi. The error ") expected" is because in your code you write storeCoordinated(evt, --> Graphics <-- g ); So this is broken Syntax. You would have to get the Graphics-Context you want to draw to and put that in there. But I suggest you stick to glowcoder's tips.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

### In response to edits:

So what I would do in this case is not use the graphics right there. Instead, I would do something like this... Keep a list of your points, and when you click, add the point to your list. Then when you draw, draw your points. (If you're only going to be drawing on click, you could just store the last point, draw a line between the current point and the last point, and set the last point to the current point. But this is more extensible.)

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Points>();

public void init() {
  addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
                    storeCoordinates(evt); // graphics removed
                }
    });
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for(int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point first = points.get(i - 1);
        Point second = points.get(i);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(first.getX(), first.getY(), second.getX(), second.getY());
    }
}

public void storeCoordinates(MouseEvent evt) {
    int x = evt.getX();
    int y = evt.getY();
    points.add(new Point(x,y));
}
```

.

#### Old Answer

Pass your graphics object as a parameter to that other method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    externalPaint(g);
}

private void externalPaint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Comment: Actually i didn't ask this. Let me make my question more clear

Comment: The issue is paint(Graphics g) is handled by the system thread. You can't use Graphics g to draw ad lib, it has to be within the paint method.

Comment: @Steve Actually, you can. You can pass that graphics object to any method you want. It works quite well to delegate your paint method. For example, `for(Person p : people) p.drawOn(g);` and then each person is responsible for drawing themselves on the graphics object. The key is that you have to call it FROM the paint method to be drawn to the screen.

Comment: @glowcoder that's what I meant the system thread has to run your code which means FROM the paint method.

Comment: may be OP's implements JApplet maybe Applet about ..paint(Graphics g)

Comment: @mKorbel could you try that again? I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.

Comment: for Applet is there paint(Graphics g) for JApplet is paintComponent(Graphics g)

Comment: @mKorbel Can you link to the URL for the `JApplet.paintComponent(Graphics)` method?  I cannot seem to find it in my JavaDocs for [JApplet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html).  ;)

Comment: @Andrew My assumption is that he meant `paintComponents(Graphics)` which is inherited from `java.awt.Container`. It does confuse me, of course, considering `JApplet` extends `Applet`, meaning `Applet` also has that method.

Answer (score 1):

> Now in another method I want to modify a scene on that was painted by the paint method. How can I do this?

Call [`Component.repaint(int,int,int,int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [`JComponent.repaint(Rectangle)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Comment: I don't want to paint the whole screen again.Just modify a bit of it

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson the OP says he wants to modify a scene that was previously painted by paint method.Then why should he call paint method again and that too on applet.That will result in flickering. Note that the event will be fired when the mouse is moved.

Comment: *"modify a **bit** of it"*  That should be expressed in your *question* given we are not psychic.  See my edit.

Comment: @program-o-steve  Are you anxious to show how it is done in code?  I notice you are not especially good at 'joining the dots', though you seem adept at voting answers down based on information that was *not present* when the answer was formulated!

Comment: I wrote in my question _modify a scene_ . And you can read the line following it.

Comment: Sure you said *"modify a scene"* in the 1st post, but that is not the same as *"modify **a bit of** a scene"*.  The term  *"modify a scene"* might mean all of it.  I don't see what 'the line following it' has to do with anything.  In short, poorly expressed question.